# Check whether children exist for a hierarchical sql table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, lazy-loading, hierarchy

I am loading all first level/root units into my Treeview.

Whether a unit has children or not determines whether the treeview shows "+".

In order to make this symbol available on the left hand side of the unit name I need to check on my SQL server whether each unit has children or not. I do not need the count, just whether children exist is enough.

I even know there was once a very good rated SO solution about the same topic, but I could not find this solution with the search.

I would appreciate the solution or any helpful links :)

Code follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Unit> GetRootUnits(int templateId)
{
    List<Unit> units = new List<Unit>();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UnitId, ParentId, Name, TemplateId, HasChildren FROM Unit WHERE ParentId Is NULL AND TemplateId = @TemplateId";
        con.Open();

        var p1 = new SqlParameter("@TemplateId", templateId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Unit unit = new Unit();
                unit.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UnitId"]);
                unit.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                unit.TemplateId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TemplateId"]);
                unit.ParentId = null;
                unit.IsLazy = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["HasChildren"]);
                units.Add(unit);
            }
        }
    }        
    return units;
}
```

Update:

I tried this:

```
   SELECT Unit.UnitId, Unit.ParentId, Unit.Name, Unit.TemplateId,
      case when Exists(select null from Unit u2 where u2.ParentID = unit.UnitID)
     then 1
     else 0
     end as HasChildren
  FROM [ITMS].[dbo].[Unit]
```

My test data:

```
1   NULL    unitroot1   1
2   NULL    unitroot2   1
3   NULL    unitroot3   1
4   NULL    unitroot4   1
5   NULL    unitroot5   1
6   NULL    unitroot6   1
7   NULL    unitroot7ffds fasddfasfds fsdadsffdsa fasdadsf  1
8   NULL    flfsaklfakl 1
9   NULL    flk43053094 1
10  NULL    sdaklr0340  1
11  NULL    3405303 1
12  NULL    543ß5ß343   1
13  NULL    54ß53ß534   1
14  NULL    45o345jo435jo   1
15  NULL    as435l5l54lk5   1
16  NULL    543095454j34    1
17  NULL    45354   1
18  NULL    kl  1
19  NULL    43534   1
20  NULL    5435    1
21  NULL    1   1
22  NULL    12  1
23  NULL    bla 1
24  7   childrenOfUnitRoot7 this is a scrolling test    1
25  24  blubb   1
```

Comment: Why isn't your existing bit field `HasChildren` found on your `unit` table sufficient?

Comment: Or are you asking for the correct SQL to assign to `cmd.CommandText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get information whether a parent has any children and return that info in `HasChildren` column, you might use exists:

```
case when exists (select null from Unit u2 where u2.ParentID = unit.UnitID)
     then 1
     else 0
     end as HasChildren
```

Alternatively, you might go for [apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT Unit.UnitId, Unit.ParentId, Unit.Name, Unit.TemplateId, 
       isnull(c.HasChildren, 0) HasChildren
  FROM Unit 
 -- Get first child record. Returns null record if not found.
 OUTER APPLY
 (
   select top 1
          1 as HasChildren
     from Unit u2
    where u2.ParentID = Unit.UnitID
 ) c
 WHERE Unit.ParentId Is NULL 
   AND Unit.TemplateId = @TemplateId
```

Third option would be to join `Unit` to derived version of `Unit` itself:

```
SELECT Unit.UnitId, Unit.ParentId, Unit.Name, Unit.TemplateId, 
    -- If c.ParentID is not null we know that there must be
    -- at least one child for this UnitID
       case when c.ParentID is not null then 1 else 0 end HasChildren
  FROM Unit 
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    select distinct ParentID
      from Unit
  ) c
    ON Unit.UnitID = c.ParentID
  WHERE Unit.ParentId Is NULL 
    AND Unit.TemplateId = @TemplateId
```

And finally, if this is Sql Server 2008, there is [HierarchyId datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx). I haven't used it, so I cannot give you first-hand impressions, but it is definitely worth looking at.

Comment: I tried your first code sample. With my data the HasChildren is always 0 ? argh... When does SO introduce complex comments with code? its such a mess... I will update my init post.

Comment: @Pascal See what results you get when you run the query from SSMS.

Comment: This is what I just did ;-) updated my post now. I think your 2nd suggestion is not for my scenario: It returns ONLY a record if there are children. But I want all root units and a 1 or 0 for the HasChildren field.

Comment: @Pascal Take a look at [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8475/2). 7 has children and 24 has children.

Comment: OUTER APPLY will work. CROSS APPLY would return only the rows having children. Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8475/4)

Comment: Sorry Nikola for causing you trouble and waste of time. It works. It was my fault. In sql management studio I had set the database to "master" not ITMS. I did not set that. I happened automatically. Thanks for your 3 suggestions I will have to find out which is the fastest (maybe you have knowledge about that too?) and maybe I check the hierarchyid. Too bad there is no EF support for that.

Comment: @Pascal No problem. We are all human :-) With index on ParentID I think they would all perform similar, but I would not stick my arm in fire...